# Laravel 8 - Route Doesn't return the Method Value

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-8, php-7.4

I have a class called UserController that has the following function :

```
public function getOrders()
{
    $user = User::findOrFail(auth()->id());

    if ($user->hasRole('customer')) {

        $washOrders = User::join('washes as w', 'w.customer_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->where('w.customer_id', $user->id)
    ->where('w.status', 'done')
    ->orWhere('w.status', 'canceled')
            ->get(['w.*']);

        $currentWash = Wash::where('customer_id', $user->id)->where('status', 'requested')->orWhere('status', 'doing')->firstOrFail();

    } else{
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'you don\'t have a permission for this route',
            'status' => 403
        ], 403);
    }

    return response()->json([
       'data' => [
           'current' => new WashResource($currentWash),
           'washes' => WashResource::collection($washOrders)
       ]
    ]);
}
```

and this is the route of that function in api.php:

```
Route::get('orders', [UserController::class, 'getOrders'])->name('orders');
```

but when i call this route , response is :

[image]

why is this happened?

Comment: seach your file for "dump(" ...

Comment: check your `WashResource` class for `dd()`